# SQL Query Not Returning Results in Visual Basic

Tags: sql-server, vb6

```vb
Private Sub ExecuteSearchBtn_Click()
     Dim cn As New ADODB.connection
     cn.connectionString = "DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=OMITTED;UID=OMITTED;PWD=OMITTED"
     cn.Open
     Dim rs2 As New ADODB.Recordset
     rs2.Open "Select * From ebs_rdh WHERE last_name LIKE '%SearchText.text%'", cn
     If Not rs2.EOF Then
         While Not rs2.EOF
             SearchResults.AddItem rs2("first_name").Value & " " & rs2("last_name").Value
             rs2.MoveNext
         Wend
     End If
```

[image]

Trying to query a SQL database from an internal application. I have a search function defined, but when the last name is typed in, no results are returned. But it doesn't crash or error out either. What am I missing?

Comment: right now you're searching for string `SearchText.text`, surely you want to fetch the value from the text box? Plus, watch out for sql injections when you do, Also vb6, really?

Comment: In addition to what @siggemannen said, [use a parameterized query](https://www.dbdelta.com/why-parameters-are-a-best-practice/): `Select * From ebs_rdh WHERE last_name LIKE '%' + ? + '%'`.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
WHERE last_name LIKE '%SearchText.text%'"
```

to

```
WHERE last_name LIKE'%" & SearchText.text & "%'"
```

It's important to look at how to use parameterization in VB6. Search fields are great for SQL injection and it is very easy.

---

Add a reference to
Microsoft Activex Data Access Object 2.8 - you probably have
Microsoft ADO Ext 2.8 For DDL and Security

Then look up using DB Paramterization in VB6